# Minimizing $4x^2-4x|\sin\theta|-\cos^2\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the minimum value of 
$$4x^2-4x|\sin\theta|-\cos^2\theta$$
over real $x$ and $\theta$.

Comment: Do you mean $$f(x)=4x^2-4x|\sin(\theta)|-\cos^2(\theta)$$?

Comment: No such thing has been specified in the question. Even I was confused by this, whether to treat $\theta=x$ or to take both as different!

Comment: Do you want to minimise over $\theta$ or over $x$ (or both)? If you want to minimise over $x$, then what is the domain of possible $x$ you want to minimise over?

Comment: We've to minimise over both. Both belong to $x\epsilon\R$ and $\theta\epsilon\R$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given,
$4x^2-4x|\sin\theta|-\cos^2\theta$
Now, adding and subtracting $\sin^2\theta$
The equation becomes
$(4x^2+\sin^2\theta-4x|\sin\theta|)-\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta$

The bracketed portion of the Function is of the form $(a-b)^2$ . And we know the equality of $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$ .
So, reducing the terms.
$(2x-|\sin\theta|)^2-(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta)$
This reduces to 
$(2x-|\sin\theta|)^2-1$
Now, we know, the minimum value of $(2x-|\sin\theta|)^2$ can be only $0$, irrespective of $x$ and $\theta$ . 
So, by applying that we get that the minimum value of the equation is $-1$ .